# Twenty Thirteen Footer Widgets Not Aligning

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a dev site here that is using a child theme of twenty thirteen.

http://unitedconstruction.com/dev/

I have 3 footer widgets but they won't line up on one line, even though their width is correct. I think it has something to do with the code that gets automatically embeded in the aside code below:

```
<div class="widget-area masonry" style="position: relative; height: 765px;">
    <aside class="widget widget_flexible-recent-posts-widget masonry-brick" id="flexible-recent-posts-widget-3" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div class="frp-widget-wrapper frp-widget-">
            <div class="frp-clear"></div>
            <ul class="frp-widget">
                <!-- Widget Code -->
            </ul>
        <div class="frp-all-category-news frp-all-category-news-footer"><a href="?page_id=7">read more &gt;&gt;</a></div>
    </div>
    </aside>
    <aside class="widget arpw-widget-random masonry-brick" id="arpw-widget-2" style="position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 0px;">
        <h3 class="widget-title"><span>United</span> Projects</h3>
        <div class="arpw-random-otw-portfolio ">
            <ul class="arpw-ul">
                <!-- Widget Code -->
            </ul>
        </div>
                <!-- Generated by https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-random-posts-widget/ --><a title="See more Projects" href="http://unitedconstruction.com/dev/projects/">read more &gt;&gt; </a>
    </aside>
    <aside class="widget widget_flexible-recent-posts-widget masonry-brick" id="flexible-recent-posts-widget-2" style="position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 382px;">
        <div class="frp-widget-wrapper frp-widget-">
            <div class="frp-clear"></div>
            <ul class="frp-widget">
                <!-- Widget Code -->
            </ul>
            <div class="frp-all-category-news frp-all-category-news-footer"><a href="http://unitedconstruction.com/in-the-community/">read more &gt;&gt;</a></div>
        </div>
    </aside>        
</div>
```

You can see that the second and third aside codes have this hardcoded: `style="position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 382px;"` and I believe that thie `left 530px` is killing the alignment. The problem is that I don't know where or how to change this.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Your sidebars are being absolutely positioned for some reason. There is some script that does this. Find the js code that controls this, and remove it, and they should fit.

Comment: I figured that, it is something that has always been programmed into theTwenty Thirteen theme. I was hoping someone here with more experience with the theme would be able to point me in the right directions. I looked in js/functions.js but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with the "masonry" grid... try adding this code:

```
.site-footer .widget {position:static !important;}
```